Two constructions of normalised chain complex from a simplicial abelian group
Given a simplicial abelian group $A_*$, one can construct its normalised chain complex
$(NA_\bullet:=\bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathrm{Ker}~d_i,(-1)^nd_n)$,
who has the same homology group as $(A_\bullet,\partial_n:=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^id_i)$.
nLab claims that there is also another construction $(NA_\bullet:=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathrm{Ker}~d_i,d_0)$, and I'm trying to verify this.
Goerss and Jardine's Simplicial Homotopy Theory (Theorems III.2.1 and III.2.4), and this exercise sheet give proof of the first construction.
The idea is as follows:
Define $D^kA_n:=\sum_{j=0}^ks_j(A_{n-1})$ and $N^kA_n:=\bigcap_{i=0}^k\mathrm{Ker}~d_i^{[n]}$ with $k=0,\cdots,n-1$, one can show that $D^k\oplus N^k\cong A_n$, and $\partial(D^kA_n)\subseteq D^kA_{n-1}$.
My question is: this idea does not work for the second construction if we set $d_0$ to be the boundary map, since $\partial(D^kA_n)\subseteq\mathrm{Im}~s_k+\mathrm{Im}~s_{k-1}$. Then how does one show that the second construction is also true?

nLab may have just made a typo
